# Using javascript to pull specific page text, and then write to a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, schema.org, microdata

I am currently trying to mark up my website product pages with product rating microdata for google SERP benefits.

The current cart software I am using does have a product rating system. It generates the following html related to the product's rating:

```
<span id="dnn_ctr783_ProductDetails_ctl02_lblAvgStars2">Average Rating: 5 Stars</span>
```

I am able to add the schema.org identifier to this span tag to produce the following:

```
<span id="dnn_ctr783_ProductDetails_ctl02_lblAvgStars2" itemprop="ratingValue">Average Rating: 5 Stars</span>
```

However, the value specified in the span tag is not valid with schema.org. They require that the "ratingValue" only contain a single digit to specify the rating. My span tag has a lot of additional text.

Somehow, I need to pull the number "5" from the generated rating span tag, and write it into another span tag which will have the proper value for the schema.org product markup.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it's unlikely that search engines will execute any kind of javascript when crawling your site, so this technique would only work on regular browsers, but would have no effect in search engines.

Comment: This is true. I wish there was a way to grab this data before the page is rendered and display it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[itemprop="ratingValue"]').each(function() {
   var txt = $(this).text(),
       rating = txt.replace(/\D/g, '' );
       // This will replace all the non-numeric instances

   $('<span/>', {
      'class' : 'newRatingValue',
      text    : rating
   }).appendTo('#div1');
   // Append this to a new span and remove the current span
   $(this).remove();
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRtbx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details on how this span is created and used?
This should get your value if you just want a single digit in a span with the 'itemprop' attribute.

```
$('[itemprop="ratingValue"]').text().match(/\d/g)
```